# Загрузка fragment через определенное время

Tags: android, android-fragment

Я использую в своем приложении динамические фрагменты. Чтобы загрузить какой-нибудь из фрагментов достаточно нажать на view, к которому прицеплен onclicklistner. Если на эти view нажимать поочередно очень быстро, то один фрагмент заменяется другим с такой же скоростью. В таком случае у меня приложение падает, поскольку на одном из фрагментов есть AsyncTask, который не успевает выполниться и падает по null в месте textview.setText(данные из AsyncTask). Так вот, есть ли какие-нибудь стандартные способы или библиотеки для загрузки фрагментов через определенное время? К примеру, нажал я на view, которая запускает фрагмент А, затем сразу же нажал на view, которая запускает фрагмент Б, но фрагмент Б не запускается, поскольку не прошло, к примеру, 2 секунды. Как только пройдет 2 секунды, так я смогу нажать на view для запуска фрагмента Б. А пока не прошло 2 секунды, можно нажимать сколь угодно раз, фрагмент не запустится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем случае можно и другие варианты предложить.

Первое - при запуске `AsyncTask` запрещать менять фрагменты пока он не отработает. (`setEnabled(false)` для `view`)

Второе - при запуске ставить флаг и не давать менять фрагменты пока не отработает  `AsyncTask` (`if(flag){...}`)

Третье некрасивое - завернуть в `try-catch` и не волноваться, но тут проблемы, что может запускаться несколько `asynctask`.

Comment: Можно и так, но в таком случае один фрагмент будет запускаться быстро, а второй - через некоторое время. У пользователя может возникнуть некий диссонанс. Да и такая реализация некрасива с точки зрения симметрии.

Comment: @SergeyMolyak можно уведомлять, что выполняется действие. К тому же, отработает ли гарантированно за отведенное время `AsyncTask`? Ну либо если так хотите, можете через `handler` запускать с `postDelayed` ну и снова же здесь флаг пригодится.